# How to target more than one element using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
 function showPage(){
   var id=document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("href"); 
    alert(id);
  }
```

```html
<a href="#link1" id="link" onclick="showPage();">Div 1</a><br>
<a href="#link2" id="link" onclick="showPage();">div 2</a><br>
```

Somebody Please help me for finding this issue

On clicking that link its alerts only #link1 not showing #link2

Comment: You should not have the same id for both element. ID should be unique.

Comment: Please put the error in the title, not just "Fix this".

Comment: @Ageonix if it bothers you...you can always edit it and gain some rep.

Comment: Unless I'm missing it, he never actually posted the js error.

Comment: @Ageonix there is no error ... OP is having problem figuring out how to target more than one element

Answer (score 2):

You can't repeat ID's in a page. If you want to target the element that event occurs on pass in `this` as parameter in the html.

Then use an argument in the function for the element represented by `this`

HTML

```
<a href="#link1" id="link-1" onclick="showPage(this);">Div 1</a><br>
<a href="#link2" id="link-2" onclick="showPage(this);">div 2</a><br>
```

JS

```
function showPage(element){
    var hash = element.hash;
    // OR
    var hash = element.getAttribute('href');    
    alert(hash);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only One Id in a Page in Same Name 
So You use Like this

```js
 function showPage(link){
   var id=document.getElementById(link).getAttribute("href"); 
    alert(id);
  }
```

```html
<a href="#link1" id="link" onclick="showPage('link');">Div 1</a><br>
<a href="#link2" id="link1" onclick="showPage('link1');">div 2</a><br>
```